# Can't get Custom Admin Tab to work!! (Very detailed of what I have thus far)

Tags: magento-1.7, module, custom

I have Magento 1.7 and I'm trying to create a custom tab in the admin panel to change customer attributes that I have created.

First off I created:
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php
which copies /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php

I want to do this correct, so I'm not changing the core files!
Inside the function _beforeToHtml() I have the following code:

```
$this->addTab('Custom',array(
       'label' =>Mage::helper('customer')->__('Custom Info'),
       'class' =>   'ajax',
       'url'   =>   $this->getUrl('*/*/custom',array('_current'=>true)),
        ));
```

This code alone creates the Custom Info tab in the picture!
[image]

When I click the tab nothing happens of course so I tried adding code to fix that!

I copied: /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
to /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
and added the following code:

```
public function customAction()
    {
        $this->_initCustomer();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customtab/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_custom','admin.customer.custom')->setCustomerId(Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
                ->setUseAjax(true)
                ->toHtml()
        );
    }
```

Next, I created the file:
/app/code/local/Sean/CustomTab/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Custom.php
and that file contains:

```
<?php

class Sean_CustomTab_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Custom extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('customtab/customer/tab/custom.phtml');
    }
}
```

Then, I created:
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customtab/customer/tab/custom.phtml
Where I just have

Hello World!

And Lastly I enable the extension through
app/etc/modules/Sean_CustomTab where I have the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_CustomTab>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sean_CustomTab>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I Refresh the Magento Cache! but alas nothing happens when I click the Custom Info tab it just shows the loading icon then it goes back to as if I never clicked it!  Please help I'll be here responding to answers and questions to clarify is there a typo? Or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an event instead. The code below is for the Admin User, but it should also work for the customer area:

```
/**
 * Adds a tab to the Admin User account (System > Permissions > Users)
 *
 * Event(s): core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after
 *
 * @param  Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function injectTabs($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

    // add tab in admin edit page
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tabs) {
        $helper = Mage::helper('adminhtml');

        $block->addTabAfter(
            'workflow',
            array(
                'label'     => $helper->__('Workflow Info'),
                'title'     => $helper->__('Workflow Info'),
                'content'   => $block->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('workflow/adminhtml_permissions_user_edit_tab_workflow')
                    ->toHtml(),
            ),
            'roles_section'
        );
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Make sure you only put it in the Adminhtml area of the config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Some_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Some_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <somemod>
                <class>Some_Module_Helper</class>
            </somemod>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <somemod>
                <class>Some_Module_Block</class>
            </somemod>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <somemod>
                <class>Some_Module_Model</class>
            </somemod>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
                <observers>
                    <somemod_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>somemod/event_observer</class>
                        <method>injectTabs</method>
                    </somemod_observer>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Do I keep any of my current code? It sounds like you're saying I can create a new custom module sean/new_module that has an etc and a Model folder, where I put config.xml inside the etc and the observer in the model?

Comment: You can keep your current code for now, but disable the call to "addTab()"... also you need a Block to render for the contents (your current Block above should be fine).

Comment: okay sounds good let me try it. I'm going to put an etc folder and model folder inside CustomTab

Comment: does anything else need to go into the config.xml besides what you listed above?

Comment: also it's giving me a slight error i can't hve public function inside my observer since it's outside of the class so will it still work as just "function injectTabs?"

Comment: Yes, the basic config stuff. Required for this would be the MODULES section (defines version), the GLOBAL section with at least BLOCKS, MODELS, and HELPERS defined.

Comment: The observer function needs to be inside the class that is named to match what is defined in the config.xml.  I updated the code in the example to include the minimum config, and based on those updates, the observer class would be: Some_Module_Model_Event_Observer. You can change it to your own observer class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a different way without using an observer 
(Sorry I'm not very experienced with observers).

I used this to tell Magento where to look to find my files.
I created a custom module:
app/etc/modules/Sean_CustomerTab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_CustomerTab>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sean_CustomerTab>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next, I created app/code/local/Sean/CustomerTab/etc/config.xml
This defined the blocks, layouts, and modules I'm going to use in Admin

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_CustomerTab>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Sean_CustomerTab>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customertab>
                    <file>customertab.xml</file>
                </customertab>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sean_customertab before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sean_CustomerTab_Adminhtml</sean_customertab>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <customertab>
                <class>Sean_CustomerTab_Block</class>
            </customertab>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then I added app/code/local/Sean/CustomerTab/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Action.php
So that I could mimic how the other tabs work in the Admin backend

(My Tab isn't Pinocchio, he's a real boy!)

```
<?php

/**
 * Adminhtml customer action tab
 *
 */
class Sean_CustomerTab_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Action
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('customertab/action.phtml');
    }

    public function getCustomtabInfo()
    {
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        $customtab = 'Mail Order Comics Pull List';
        return $customtab;
    }

    /**
     * Return Tab label
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Customer Pull List');
    }

    /**
     * Return Tab title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Pull List Tab');
    }

    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        return (bool)$customer->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Defines after which tab, this tab should be rendered
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAfter()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }
}
```

After that I created app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customertab.xml
Here I'm saying use the method addTab and insert the block

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>customer_edit_tab_action</name>
                <block>customertab/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_action</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

Now I have app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customertab/action.phtml
Where I can do all my awesome html and it shows perfectly

AND I also have app/code/local/Sean/CustomerTab/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomerTabController.php for a custom controller to act with that html page!

@Phil Mobley I'll upvote your answer, you helped me think of a way to do this!

RESULT: [image]